# Obtaining values from processes and updating initial values in multiprocessing - Python

Tags: python

```
class Obj1(object):
    def __init__(self):     
        self.var = 1

    def func1(self, r):
        self.var = self.var + 2

class Obj2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.arr = []
        self.arr.append(Obj1())

    def parallel_func(self, i):
        self.arr[i].func1(i)
        print "11111  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", self.arr[i].var

    def func3(self):
        for i in range (3)
            for i in range (2):
                p = Process(target = self.parallel_func, args = (i,))
                p.start()
                print "22222  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", self.arr[i].var
                p.join()

if __name__=='__main__':
    var = Obj2()
    var.func3()
```

**Objective:** To use oops & multiprocessing concept for parallelizing "parallel_func" in the code

**Problem:** As per expectations, both print statements should give the same output. But, they are providing different results. For each iteration the individual process refer the first initialized variable and not its previous values. I need the process to use its previous processes result.

**Question:**
1. Since I used oops concept, I would like to know how the global variables are handled inside the objects.
2. Is there any other way to update the variables after each process completes so that the next one gets the latest value. I have tried queue concept and still the problem remains.
3. Could multiprocessing.manager functionality solve this issue? If yes, could you please help me with it?
4. Any other way of solving this would be highly appreciated.